# Unexpected thread executing

Tags: java, multithreading

Running the code:

```
Thread tt = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
        });
System.out.println(tt.getName());
tt.run();
```

I would expect to get:

```
Thread-0
Thread-0
```

But instead I get:

```
Thread-0
main
```

Why is that?

Comment: Call `start()` on Threads, not `run()`.

Comment: Yep, sorry for being stupid :-(

Answer (score 0):

Your Thread's run method doesn't do anything. The Runnable's run method calls println, but in your code it's never run. Call `start()` on the thread not `run()`